# Autorerun failed rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have some code in my tests which works with some external service. This service is not very stable, so sometimes it crash for no reason. But in 80% of runs it works well.

So I want a method to automatically rerun all failed rspecs several time (for example 2 or 3 time).
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Many people would say that your test actually should never hit external services, and that's one of the reasons to do it. Your tests should not fail because some external service is down.

TL;DR use mocks and stubs or to replace those external service calls

Comment: VCR (https://github.com/vcr/vcr) is a nice approach as well. It records the first call to the external service and saves it to a "cassette". The next time the test is run, it uses the cassette rather than external service directly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-running failed specs, couldn't you just run the method accessing the service a set number of times and run the expectation on the logical OR of the results?

So instead of:

```
it "returns expected value for some args" do
   unstable_external_service(<some args>).should == <expected return value>
end
```

just do something like this:

```
def run_x_times(times, args)
  return nil if times == 0
  unstable_external_service(args) || run_x_times(times-1)
end

it "returns expected value for some args" do
  run_x_times(10, <some args>).should == <expected return value>
end
```

You can use the same wrapper method throughout your tests anytime you access the service. I'm assuming here that your service returns `nil` on a failure, but if not you could change this to fit your particular case -- you get the general idea.

Comment: Problem that external service can return no value and this will be correct result (for example 'there is no new messages on mail') so I can't know condition in which usage of external service may be flagged as 'correct'

Comment: So what are you testing in your expectation? Whatever that value is, just check it a few times and if it matches once, then use that value in the expectation.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will be my backup plan if there is no easy way to rerun failed specs